# CSS feature detection using media queries

Tags: css, feature-detection

I'm trying to detect if the browser supports the `transform` property.

To do so I'm wrapping the code I want to apply when the `transform` is supported inside a media query:

```
@media (transform: none) {
  // My code 
}
```

With this code, this part is not triggered.

The initial state of `transform` is `none` so I'm wondering why it doesn't trigger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at [the most recent media queries spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/), this is not possible.

Also,  to quotefrom [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#partial) in the spec:

> CSS renderers must treat as invalid (and ignore as appropriate) any at-rules, properties, property values, keywords, and other syntactic constructs for which they have no usable level of support.

Ignoring anything inside is to adhere to the spec.

Comment: ah damn, perfect example of how to limit some useful feature... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes its true. You can't detect features with media queries (just for the record). But you can use feature queries instead.

[You can detect CSS features with "feature queries" (the `@supports` rule).](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-conditional-3/#at-supports)

```
@supports (transform: none) {
  // browser supports transform property
}
@supports not (transform: none) {
  // browser doesn't support transform property
}
```

But this particular example (feature detection against the `transform` property) is kind a bit tricky. If we have a look at caniuse we can see that there a [some browser that don't support the `@supports` rule](https://caniuse.com/#search=%40supports) but actually [support the `transform` property](https://caniuse.com/#search=transform) (eg IE9-11).

Those browser will detect false false, so to say. Those browser will ignore feature queries even though they support the actual feature that we like to detect.